# Jcontroller Unknown class

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

Hi I am new to Joomla and PHP and working on **Joomla 3.4** to create a controller.

However I am getting the error as **unknown class:'JController'**

I am using the below code in my controller.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die("Access Deny");
jimport('joomla.controller');
class MycompController extends JController{
    function display(){
        echo JText::_('COM_MYCOMP_WELCOME');
    }
    function create(){
        echo JText::_('Create a ner task');
    }
    function list_task(){
        echo JText::_('Create a list task');    
    }
    function help(){
        echo JText::_('Help Section: Checkout the docs');    
    }
}
?>
```

I know its only related to including controller.php from its path. But I am not getting by using jimport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are on Joomla! 3.x? In which case JController is no longer used as it is being deprecated.

You need to use JControllerLegacy See:

https://docs.joomla.org/JController_and_its_subclass_usage_overview

On other controller usages.